# "Forgot password " for zfcuser

Tags: zend-framework2, zfcuser, zfc-rbac

I am using zfcuser and zfcrbac. ZfcUser does not have "forgot password" (or reset password) functionality complete. What is the best module there to use for resetting password functionality ? Ideally, I'd like to use emails with tokenized links, but any good solution would be helpful.

Comment: This is what you are looking for. https://github.com/Eye4web/Eye4webZfcUserForgotPassword And please do a search before asking here...

Comment: Appreciate your response with a link. I did a search and few options came out. But some of them are clearly stating that they are incomplete, some are not much supported, and others do not have much in readme explanation. So, sounds to me like a case to ask experts. Btw, are there any instructions for this module ? (I searched, and keep searching)

Comment: Not sure for instructions. However, I have coded my own reset password with send email options with a link and a token, where the token expires after 24 hours, but it's not connected with zfcuser. If needed I can post the code here later.

Comment: Thanks. I actually found some installation instructions in their docs folder. I'll see if I succeed to use it with zfcuser. If you get a chance, your code example is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I've been using this module with ease for 4 ZF2 projects already https://github.com/goalio/GoalioForgotPassword

It's simple and well crafted enough so that you can override any behaviour easily if needed.

Ex: we use this module but modified a factory to use our usual external email provider.

Comment: I ended up using Eye4web/Eye4webZfcUserForgotPassword , and sendmail transport.

Comment: The code looks good but this repo was too young and untested for me.